# How do I change heroku from web npm start to worker npm start?

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have a heroku app that doesn't have a website - however, I mistakenly set it up with a web npm start. I'm looking to fix it as it's been throwing an error about failing to bind to $PORT. How exactly should I change it?

EDIT: Directory: src folder, .gitignore, Procfile, readme.md, package-lock.json, package.json

Content of Procfile: worker: npm start

Comment: Do you already have a `Procfile`?

Comment: Yes? I'm not sure how I should work with that procfile but it's there.

Comment: The procfile is 
   
worker: npm start

Comment: Is it called `Procfile` or `procfile`? Or `Procfile.txt`, or something else? Is it in the root (top) directory of your project?

Comment: Yes, it's named "Procfile" in the root directory.

Comment: Please show us the contents of the file and a directory listing by [edit]ing them into your question.

Comment: Has been done. What more?

Comment: I'm looking for the actual output from a command, not what you _think_ these files are called. Please run `ls` in the top-level directory, then copy and paste the output into your question as a code block. Or show a screenshot of the top-level directory.